# How to change Play / Pause keyboard shortcut of Rhythmbox?

Tags: gnome, rhythmbox

In the [official list of Rhythmbox shortcuts](https://help.gnome.org/users/rhythmbox/stable/shortcuts.html.en) I found that we can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to *Play / Pause* music in Rhythmbox.

But I want to change it to <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to follow these steps:

1. Open the Settings → *Keyboard* panel.
2. Then, click the *View and Customize Shortcuts* button at the bottom.
3. In the opened list, click *Sound and Media*.
4. Then just click on the *Play (or play/pause)* selection and set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> as a shortcut.

   [image: Sound and Media window with Play (or play/pause) option highlighted]

With this, both the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> shortcuts work to play/pause on Rhythmbox.